# Getting error while creating managed disk from a VHD file in a storage account in the same subscription with CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli, azure-cli2, azure-disk

Facing issue while creating managed disk from a VHD file in a storage account in the same subscription with CLI.

I have replicated/copied managed disk icremental snapshot from westus region to eastus region using below script.

```
#Provide the name of your resource group where snapshot is created
sourceResourceGroupName=""
drSnapshotResourceGroupName=""

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the snapshot.
drSnapshotStorageAccountName=""

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded snapshot will be stored
storageContainerName=""

#Provide Shared Access Signature (SAS) expiry duration in seconds e.g. 3600.
#Know more about SAS here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1
sasExpiryDuration=36000

#Provide the key of the storage account where you want to copy snapshot.
storageAccountKey=$(az storage account keys list -g $drSnapshotResourceGroupName -n $drSnapshotStorageAccountName --query [0].value -otsv)

SNAPSHOT_NAMES=$(az snapshot list -g $sourceResourceGroupName --query "[?tags.COMPONENT== 'database'].name" --output tsv)

for snapshot_name in $SNAPSHOT_NAMES
do
        #Provide the snapshot name
        snapshotName=$snapshot_name

        #Provide the name of the VHD file to which snapshot will be copied.
        destinationVHDFileName="$snapshot_name.vhd"

     
        sas=$(az snapshot grant-access --resource-group $sourceResourceGroupName --name $snapshotName \
                --duration-in-seconds $sasExpiryDuration --query [accessSas] -o tsv)

        az storage blob incremental-copy start --destination-blob $destinationVHDFileName \
        --destination-container $storageContainerName --account-name $drSnapshotStorageAccountName \
        --account-key $storageAccountKey --source-uri $sas
done
```

I am trying to create managed disk from copied vhd in eastus region using az cli using below script.

```
#Provide the name of your resource group where snapshot is created
drSnapshotResourceGroupName=""

#Provide the name of your resource group.
#Ensure that resource group is already created
drResourceGroupName=""

#Provide storage account name where you want to copy the snapshot.
drSnapshotStorageAccountName=""

#Name of the storage container where the downloaded snapshot will be stored
storageContainerName=""

#Provide the name of the Managed Disk
diskName=disknametocreatefromvhd

#Provide the size of the disks in GB. It should be greater than the VHD file size.
diskSize=512


#Provide the URI of the VHD file that will be used to create Managed Disk.
# VHD file can be deleted as soon as Managed Disk is created.
# e.g. https://contosostorageaccount1.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/contosovhd123.vhd
vhdUri=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/asdf/abcd.vhd

#Provide the storage type for the Managed Disk. Premium_LRS or Standard_LRS.
storageType=Premium_LRS

#Provide the Azure location (e.g. westus) where Managed Disk will be located.
location=eastus

echo "Creating managed disk from the VHD file"

#Create the Managed disk from the VHD file
az disk create --resource-group ${drResourceGroupName} --name ${diskName} \
                --sku $storageType --location $location \
                --size-gb $diskSize --source $vhdUri
```

Getting below mentioned Error in az disk create.

```
request failed: Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/32d45ca1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/DR02-Recovery/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/draas-snapshot-database-vm0-osdisk-asdf?api-version=2019-11-01 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))
```

Adding complete debug output here.

```
Command arguments: ['disk', 'create', '--resource-group', 'RG_NAME', '--name', 'abcd-osdisk', '--sku', 'Premium_LRS', '--location', 'eastus', '--size-gb', '512', '--source', 'https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/asdf/abcd-osdisk.vhd', '--debug']
Event: Cli.PreExecute []
Event: CommandParser.OnGlobalArgumentsCreate [<function CLILogging.on_global_arguments at 0x7fa05b4d5d90>, <function OutputProducer.on_global_arguments at 0x7fa05b2aad90>, <function CLIQuery.on_global_arguments at 0x7fa05b052048>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableCreate []
Installed command modules ['acr', 'acs', 'advisor', 'ams', 'apim', 'appconfig', 'appservice', 'aro', 'backup', 'batch', 'batchai', 'billing', 'botservice', 'cdn', 'cloud', 'cognitiveservices', 'configure', 'consumption', 'container', 'cosmosdb', 'deploymentmanager', 'dla', 'dls', 'dms', 'eventgrid', 'eventhubs', 'extension', 'feedback', 'find', 'hdinsight', 'interactive', 'iot', 'iotcentral', 'keyvault', 'kusto', 'lab', 'managedservices', 'maps', 'monitor', 'natgateway', 'netappfiles', 'network', 'policyinsights', 'privatedns', 'profile', 'rdbms', 'redis', 'relay', 'reservations', 'resource', 'role', 'search', 'security', 'servicebus', 'servicefabric', 'signalr', 'sql', 'sqlvm', 'storage', 'util', 'vm']
Loaded module 'acr' in 0.007 seconds.
Loaded module 'acs' in 0.008 seconds.
Loaded module 'advisor' in 0.001 seconds.
Event: CommandLoader.OnLoadCommandTable []
Loaded module 'ams' in 0.006 seconds.
Loaded module 'apim' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'appconfig' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'appservice' in 0.223 seconds.
Loaded module 'aro' in 0.005 seconds.
Loaded module 'backup' in 0.004 seconds.
Event: CommandLoader.OnLoadCommandTable []
Loaded module 'batch' in 0.028 seconds.
Loaded module 'batchai' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'billing' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'botservice' in 0.003 seconds.
Event: CommandLoader.OnLoadCommandTable []
Loaded module 'cdn' in 0.005 seconds.
Loaded module 'cloud' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'cognitiveservices' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'configure' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'consumption' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'container' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'cosmosdb' in 0.008 seconds.
Loaded module 'deploymentmanager' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'dla' in 0.004 seconds.
Loaded module 'dls' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'dms' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'eventgrid' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'eventhubs' in 0.004 seconds.
Loaded module 'extension' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'feedback' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'find' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'hdinsight' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'interactive' in 0.000 seconds.
Loaded module 'iot' in 0.005 seconds.
Loaded module 'iotcentral' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'keyvault' in 0.006 seconds.
Loaded module 'kusto' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'lab' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'managedservices' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'maps' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'monitor' in 0.009 seconds.
Loaded module 'natgateway' in 0.001 seconds.
Event: CommandLoader.OnLoadCommandTable []
Loaded module 'netappfiles' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'network' in 0.035 seconds.
Loaded module 'policyinsights' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'privatedns' in 0.005 seconds.
Loaded module 'profile' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'rdbms' in 0.008 seconds.
Loaded module 'redis' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'relay' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'reservations' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'resource' in 0.011 seconds.
Loaded module 'role' in 0.004 seconds.
Loaded module 'search' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'security' in 0.004 seconds.
Loaded module 'servicebus' in 0.005 seconds.
Loaded module 'servicefabric' in 0.003 seconds.
Loaded module 'signalr' in 0.002 seconds.
Loaded module 'sql' in 0.011 seconds.
Loaded module 'sqlvm' in 0.002 seconds.
Event: CommandLoader.OnLoadCommandTable []
Loaded module 'storage' in 0.042 seconds.
Loaded module 'util' in 0.001 seconds.
Loaded module 'vm' in 0.042 seconds.
Loaded all modules in 0.560 seconds. (note: there's always an overhead with the first module loaded)
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreCommandTableTruncate [<function AzCliLogging.init_command_file_logging at 0x7fa05aa09950>]
az_command_data_logger : command args: disk create --resource-group {} --name {} --sku {} --location {} --size-gb {} --source {} --debug
metadata file logging enabled - writing logs to '/home/Test/.azure/commands'.
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreArgumentLoad [<function register_global_subscription_argument.<locals>.add_subscription_parameter at 0x7fa05aa2cae8>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostArgumentLoad []
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostCommandTableCreate [<function register_ids_argument.<locals>.add_ids_arguments at 0x7fa05a9e1bf8>, <function register_cache_arguments.<locals>.add_cache_arguments at 0x7fa05a9e1d08>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnCommandTableLoaded []
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPreParseArgs [<function _documentdb_deprecate at 0x7fa05898b1e0>]
Event: CommandInvoker.OnPostParseArgs [<function OutputProducer.handle_output_argument at 0x7fa05b2aae18>, <function CLIQuery.handle_query_parameter at 0x7fa05b0520d0>, <function register_ids_argument.<locals>.parse_ids_arguments at 0x7fa05a9e1c80>, <function handler at 0x7fa0587e6bf8>]
Getting management service client client_type=ComputeManagementClient
msrest.universal_http.requests : Configuring retry: max_retries=4, backoff_factor=0.8, max_backoff=90
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:50342
urllib3.connectionpool : http://localhost:50342 "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 2054
msrestazure.azure_active_directory : MSI: Retrieving a token from http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token, with payload {'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/'}
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:50342
urllib3.connectionpool : http://localhost:50342 "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 2054
msrestazure.azure_active_directory : MSI: Retrieving a token from http://localhost:50342/oauth2/token, with payload {'resource': 'https://management.core.windows.net/'}
msrest.http_logger : Request URL: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01'
msrest.http_logger : Request method: 'PUT'
msrest.http_logger : Request headers:
msrest.http_logger :     'Accept': 'application/json'
msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
msrest.http_logger :     'accept-language': 'en-US'
msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Length': '461'
msrest.http_logger :     'User-Agent': 'python/3.6.10 (Linux-4.15.0-1089-azure-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid) msrest/0.6.9 cloud-shell/1.0 msrest_azure/0.6.3 azure-mgmt-compute/12.0.0 Azure-SDK-For-Python AZURECLI/2.8.0 (DEB)'
msrest.http_logger : Request body:
msrest.http_logger : {"location": "eastus", "tags": {}, "sku": {"name": "Premium_LRS"}, "properties": {"hyperVGeneration": "V1", "creationData": {"createOption": "Import", "storageAccountId": "/subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccountname", "sourceUri": "https://storageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/asdf/abcd-osdisk.vhd"}, "diskSizeGB": 512}}
msrest.universal_http : Configuring redirects: allow=True, max=30
msrest.universal_http : Configuring request: timeout=100, verify=True, cert=None
msrest.universal_http : Configuring proxies: ''
msrest.universal_http : Evaluate proxies against ENV settings: True
urllib3.connectionpool : Starting new HTTPS connection (1): management.azure.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 125
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01'): Retry(total=3, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
urllib3.connectionpool : Retry: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01
urllib3.connectionpool : Resetting dropped connection: management.azure.com
urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 125
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01'): Retry(total=2, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)

urllib3.connectionpool : Retry: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01
urllib3.connectionpool : Resetting dropped connection: management.azure.com
urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 125
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01'): Retry(total=1, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)

urllib3.connectionpool : Retry: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01
urllib3.connectionpool : Resetting dropped connection: management.azure.com
urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 125
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01'): Retry(total=0, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)


urllib3.connectionpool : Retry: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01
urllib3.connectionpool : Resetting dropped connection: management.azure.com
urllib3.connectionpool : https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 125
msrest.exceptions : Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))


cli.azure.cli.core.util : request failed: Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))
request failed: Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/32d45ba1-b2dc-4370-a618-85e7756da78f/resourceGroups/RG_NAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/abcd-osdisk?api-version=2019-11-01 (Caused by ResponseError('too many 500 error responses',))
Event: Cli.PostExecute [<function AzCliLogging.deinit_cmd_metadata_logging at 0x7fa05aa09b70>]
az_command_data_logger : exit code: 1
telemetry.save : Save telemetry record of length 5618 in cache
telemetry.check : Returns Positive.
telemetry.main : Begin creating telemetry upload process.
telemetry.process : Creating upload process: "/opt/az/bin/python3 /opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/telemetry/__init__.py /home/vinayak/.azure"
telemetry.process : Return from creating process
telemetry.main : Finish creating telemetry upload process.
Command ran in 725.683 seconds (init: 0.048, invoke: 725.635)
```

Comment: Could you please add `--debug` to get error message?

Comment: I am trying to create managed disk from VHD file source is OS disk. Also I want to create managed data disk from VHD file source is data disk.

Comment: @JimXu Added complete debug output in summary.

Comment: According to my research, If we use `Incremental Copy Blob` to copy API, the blob may not be gotten content. So we cannot use the blob to create disk. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/incremental-copy-blob

Comment: @Jim Xu  How to check whether blob gotten content or not? I could see copy status success in blob properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is my findings on the different scenarios of the Azure incremental snapshot.

1. First Scenarios creating an incremental snapshot and was that to create a disk in the same region. This was successful with portal without any issues.

This disk can now be exported or copied to another region.

2. Second scenario copying the incremental snapshot across regions with CLI, this was successful, but we could not use this snapshot to create a disk as this method of copying the incremental snapshots was supported.

The only method to copy the incremental snapshot is to use the snapshot blob and the copy blob and then get the differential PagesRanges and Use PutPages to apply changes.

Then take a snapshot of the backup Page Blob and store in a storage account.

Find this document on using incremental snapshot for backup
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/incremental-snapshots#incremental-snapshot-copy

And this documents of a .Net code to copy incremental snapshots to another region

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/managed-disks-dotnet-backup-with-incremental-snapshots

To use for Incremental snapshot as DR/Failover to another region with Azure CLI, PowerShell or any SDK.